# Is it possible to read cookie while doing a HTTP Get to external website?

Tags: http, httprequest, httpresponse

Well was wondering if this is possible at all ? The aim is to get a cookie from an external website.

But while going through the HTTP class for both Request and Response I don't think there is a method to access this cookie and I even looked into the response header and I wasn't able to find the value there.

Is there is a workaround to read the cookie ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `response.getHeader('Set-Cookie')` to find the cookies set by the responding site.

```
HttpRequest request1 = new HttpRequest();
request1.setMethod('GET');
request1.setEndpoint('http://www.google.com/');

HttpResponse response1 = new Http().send(request1);
String cookies = getResponse.getHeader('Set-Cookie'); //semicolon-delimited keys and values
```

Then you can transmit the same cookie in a subsequent request (eg to simulate a browser session)

```
HttpRequest request2 = new HttpRequest();
request2.setMethod('GET');
request2.setEndpoint('http://www.google.com/');
request2.setHeader('Cookie', cookies);

HttpResponse response2 = new Http().send(request2);
```

Comment: My Bad I just observed that I have done the DEBUG on wrong line number. Anyways thanks